# How to set up SPADE package for discourse relation

Tags: perl, nlp, charniak-parser

I would like to test sentence level parsing for discourse relation. I already downloaded [SPADE](http://www.isi.edu/licensed-sw/spade/) from isi.edu. I set up the package according to the instructions. But it does not work. I used Padre, the Perl IDE to run the package. According to the instructions, I changed the `$CHP` variable to the path of parser like that.

```
$CHP = "D:/SIITcourse/Special Study/RhetoricalToolKit/parser/";
```

I downloaded Charniak's syntactic parser from the link at isi.edu. May I know if I need something else for parser. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you expand on "it does not work"? What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: In spite of changing the path according to his instructions, it (spade.pl) does not work. I run the program with " Run Command" by giving parameters "spade.pl [-seg-only] one-sent-per-line-file". The output from command line is " Press Any Key to Continue" and nothing comes out. Please....

Comment: @dmcc , now i put SPADE and parser together under the same folder. It is ok to run the file. But i have these errors " C:/parser/parseIt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
system C:/parser/parseIt C:/parser/DATA/ C:/SPADE/example/wsj_0616 > C:/SPADE/ex
ample/wsj_0616.chp failed: 256 at spade.pl line 38."

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are you running cygwin? The parser doesn't run by default on Windows, though there is a version that runs on Windows natively: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dorony/2013/03/02/charniak-parser-on-windows/

Comment: @dmcc. Yes. I got it. Thank you very much. I will check it out.